# PL/SQL Update column based on column ID obtained from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

My colleague and I are attempting to write a database trigger in PL/SQL that can look into a mapping table to find the ID of a specific column from another table (example tables included below) and then update the value in that column.

We need to be able to do this as a BEFORE EACH ROW trigger so that we modify the data before it is committed into the database.

We ended up writing a massive CASE statement to handle this, but does anyone know of a better way to handle this sort of situation? In our real life example, we also have 70 columns to look through, rather than 8, like in the example below.

```
create table test_basis (
  id      number(22,0) not null,
  item_1  number(22,0) not null,
  item_2  number(22,0) not null,
  item_3  number(22,0) not null,
  item_4  number(22,0) not null,
  item_5  number(22,0) not null,
  item_6  number(22,0) not null,
  item_7  number(22,0) not null,
  item_8  number(22,0) not null
)

create table basis_mapping (
  column_id    number(22,0),
  column_name  varchar2(35)
)

insert into basis_mapping(1, 'Company');
insert into basis_mapping(2, 'Account');
insert into basis_mapping(3, 'Manager');
insert into basis_mapping(4, 'User');
```

For our purposes, we need to look up the column_id from basis_mapping based on the column_name, and then update the :new.item_### field in the current row. So, if we wanted to change the value in the 'User' column, we would run the following statement

```
select column_id 
  into l_basis_id
  from basis_mapping 
  where column_name = 'User'
```

Now that we have 4 in the l_basis_id variable, how can we use this to generate a statement like the following?

```
:new.item_4 = 0
```

Comment: do it via dynamic sql.......?  I haven't done dynamic slq in oracle but here is a link on it  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: When you start having lots of columns, called "item_xxx", I would say maybe, your design of "test_basis" table is flawed.  Maybe you need a repeating, join table, or another column, "item_name", or something?

Comment: You database design looks like a key-value model (not recommended in relational databases) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126271/key-value-pairs-in-relational-database, but your model is developed to a higher (much more complicated) level of abstraction. At the very last consider normalizing the table `test_basic` to three columns: `(id, column_id, item_value )`

Comment: There is no easy way to be this sort of dynamic assignment in PL/SQL. You should take this as a pointer that you are taking the wrong approach to whatever business problem you're tackling. Your best options are to consider an approach which works with the grain of a relational database system or stick with your monster CASE statement.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very old system and these tables are incredibly centralized, so fixing the schema to what it should be isn't really an option at this point. I do appreciate the suggestions though, but it looks like we will have to stick with the CASE statement for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot refer to `:new` and `:old` in dynamic SQL. Please have a look at [Oracle PL/SQL: Loop Over Trigger Columns Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786733/oracle-pl-sql-loop-over-trigger-columns-dynamically).